# How can I show text other than "passing" or "failing" in GitHub workflow status badges?

Tags: github-actions

[GitHub workflow status badges](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/monitoring-and-troubleshooting-workflows/adding-a-workflow-status-badge) are a feature that GitHub provides for updating badges such as the ones seen in project README files on GitHub. E.g.:
[image]

**Is there a way to have an action produce status text other than "passing" or "failing"?**

I have a certain custom workflow that is not a passing/failing type of workflow but rather produces an identifier (a short text string). For users' benefit, I'd like to offer a way to update a badge with the identifier produced at the end of a workflow. The workflow status badge would be ideal, if the "status" text value could be customized.